# Variable into Nokogiri HTML parsing method

Tags: html, ruby, regex, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse an HTML document that's big, convoluted, and lacking any class or IDs in CSS. I think I can let Nokogiri do the work for me.

I will have many pages with different structures, so I think I have to use the structure I am given to find the elements that are close-by and associated.  Specifically, it's published in table cells with a name-value pair.  Using the name, which is unique, I'm guessing I can extract the value.

The page has a handful of tables.  Tables have a variable number of rows.  I would like to use the following:

```
<tr class="boxInside">
<td>
    <strong>
        Number of Employees:
    </strong>
</td>
<td>
    15&nbsp;
</td>
```

So I'm looking at something like this:

```
page.css('<strong>\s*Number of Employees:\s*<\/strong>')
```

Using regexp while extracting the second grouping would be my goal.  I'd like to bring that in as a variable, like this:

```
page.css('<strong>\s*#{searchstring}\s*<\/strong>')
```

I can't seem to get it right.  Any insight appreciated.  Using a true regexp without Nokogiri was even more confusing.

Comment: Neither of your sample CSS selectors are correct. Nokogiri's tutorials cover [how to search](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html). I'd recommend reading through the page, then trying using `page.css('strong')` as a starting point. Using a Regexp pattern is the wrong way, nor would it work because what you are trying to find is in the child text node. XPath can do it but that's not as readable.

Answer (score 0):

This will find all `<strong>` tags embedded in rows and return the text:

```
require 'nokogiri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<tr class="boxInside">
<td>
    <strong>
        Number of Employees:
    </strong>
</td>
<td>
    15&nbsp;
</td>
EOT

page.css('tr.boxInside strong').map(&:text) # => ["\n        Number of Employees:\n    "]
```

To use CSS selectors, you have to follow the rules for selecting objects. You can't just enter HTML tags. I'd recommend reading about them on one of the many tutorials or reference sites.

If you know what you want is always a cell that is a given offset from the start of the row, you can always slice the resulting NodeSet that is returned by `css`.